# How to catch unhandled exception that are raised in background thread?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have for habit to execute anonymous thread like :

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
   procedure
   begin
     .....
   end).start;
```

But the problem is that if some **unhandled** exception will raise during the execution, then i will be not warned about it! For the main thread we have `Application.OnException`. Do we have something similar for background thread ?

Answer (score 10):

`TThread` has a public [`FatalException`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.FatalException) property:

> If the `Execute` method raises an exception that is not caught and handled within that method, the thread terminates and sets `FatalException` to the exception object for that exception. **Applications can check `FatalException` from an [`OnTerminate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.OnTerminate) event handler to determine whether the thread terminated due to an exception.**

For example:

```
procedure TMyForm.DoSomething;
begin
  ...
  thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(...);
  thread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
  thread.Start;
  ...
end;

procedure TMyForm.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TThread(Sender).FatalException <> nil then
  begin
   ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Works great when using a `TThread` class, but OP is using `CreateAnonymousThread`, so might want to point that out...

Comment: @JerryDodge I'm aware that the OP is using. [`CreateAnonymousThread()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread). It returns a suspended `TThread` object, you can tweak its properties and assign event handlers to it before calling `Start()` on it

Comment: Never knew that (FatalException property...).  I think I still prefer catching and handling them in place, though.  This seems less controlled, generally.

Comment: @J... It depends on your needs. `Execute` is wrapped in a `try..except` block, and `OnTerminate` is synced with the UI thread. If you don't need that sync, you can skip the event

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks ! yes their is FatalException  but anyway it's also painless to update all existing thread to override in all of them the ThreadTerminated than using a try .. finally in each of them :(

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I see the appeal.  I think what bothers me the most is that it introduces a new error handling pattern which is specific (to TThread) rather than idiomatic. It's also more awkward to debug (by the time you break in the handler you're in a different thread, different call stack...).  The more I think about it the more reasons there are to avoid this, it seems.

Comment: @j... see my answer below, i finally decide to do it like this. exception will be handled in the current thread and thus will permit us to retrieve the current stack trace

Comment: Is it OK to `raise` the caught exception in `OnTerminate` (in this case `ThreadTerminated`)? Excuse me! Just found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17947776/2093077).

Answer (score 6):

N̶o̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶s̶i̶m̶i̶l̶a̶r̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶a̶c̶k̶g̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶r̶e̶a̶d̶.̶ (Thanks, Remy!)

The best solution is to always be absolutely certain to never let an exception escape from a thread.  Ideally, your thread procedures should look something like this :

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
   procedure
   begin
     try
       { your code}
     except
       {on E : Exception do}
       {... handle it!}            
     end;
   end).start;
```

Comment: Actually, there is something... See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I got the best answer :

Assign the global `ExceptionAcquired` procedure to our own implementation (it is nil by default). This procedure gets called for unhandled exceptions that happen in other threads than the main thread.

```
ExceptionAcquired := MyGlobalExceptionAcquiredHandler;
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer of J... and Remy Lebeau are good with what delphi offer, but i need a little more and I finally decide to modify a little the unit `System.Classes`

```
var
  ApplicationHandleThreadException: procedure (Sender: TObject; E: Exception) of object = nil;

function ThreadProc(const Thread: TThread): Integer;
  ...
  try
    Thread.Execute;
  except
    Thread.FFatalException := AcquireExceptionObject;
    if assigned(ApplicationHandleThreadException) and
       assigned(Thread.FFatalException) and
       (Thread.FFatalException is Exception) and
       (not (Thread.FFatalException is EAbort)) then
      ApplicationHandleThreadException(Thread, Exception(Thread.FFatalException));
  end;
```

in this way you just need to assign `ApplicationHandleThreadException` to handle unhandled exception raise in any TThread. You don't need to be worry about the multi thread because global var like `ExceptAddr` are declared as `threadvar` so everything work fine, even to retrieve the stack trace !

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21269

Comment: Modifying the RTL source is arguably a bad idea if you want your code to work when compiled on any system other than your own.

Comment: @J... yes i agree, especially when you upgrade delphi! But I can not imagine any descent app using firemonkey who didn't touche the RTL source !